# Where can I find the most complete possible list with raw products and their respective pH?

Tags: resources, raw

I'm looking for the most comprehensive list of raw products such as vegetables, fruits, meats, seeds, etc. used in the kitchen (Oriental Cuisine) and their respective pH. I found so many things about alkaline and acid foods, which is good to know, but I really need the pH of each one. How alkaline is it?

For example:

```
Fruits ----- Figs (raw) ----- Alkaline (How Alkaline? 7.5, 8, 9 ??)
```

Comment: Are you looking for a list of the actual pH of foods, or a list related to the psuedo-scientific Alkaline Diet (http://chriskresser.com/the-ph-myth-part-1)?

Comment: This is way, *way* too broad - you've essentially asked for the pH of every single conceivable ingredient and haven't even specified why it's important. Please narrow your question down.

Comment: I mean.. I'm looking for a list of the actual pH of foods in general (Veggies, Meats, Seeds, Fruits, ..) some public list of pH of foods. I run an Asian Food Service and I would like to provide that information to my customers.

Comment: There will be considerable variation. If you really need to know, [measure](http://www.creamsupplies.co.uk/prod_2698.html).

Comment: @B4NZ41 The vast majority of the food humans eat is either neutral (i.e. around pH 7) or slightly acidic pH <7.  You can see a list of some common fruits and vegetables at the end of this article: http://pods.dasnr.okstate.edu/docushare/dsweb/Get/Document-962/FAPC-118web.pdf  , but it is by no means a comprehensive list.  Few of your customers actually know what pH is and even fewer of them care what the pH of their food is.  Additionally, both the act of cooking ingredients and the act of mixing ingredients will change the pH of the dish.

Comment: You can't simply average the pH of each ingredient and tell your customers that the dish is that pH. First, it would be untrue. The only way to come by the actual pH would be to measure the actual dish with pH paper or an electronic pH tester as @Peter Taylor suggested. Second, it implies that there is health or nutritional value in that fact. A claim which there is little to no evidence to support.

Comment: If somebody wonders, I cleaned up the prolonged comments discussion and left only the informative ones. If more discussion is needed, it can happen in our normal chat, or you guys can create a special chat room for it.

Answer (score 3):

[This list](http://dpcpress.com/ph_foods.html) is probably the extensive I've seen on the Internet with some scientific accuracy behind it. A more condensed list with great references at the bottom can also be [found here](http://www.foodsafety.wisc.edu/business_food/files/Approximate_pH.pdf).

The numbers seem to jive with my own experience, especially in the high variance of some of the foods.

As some of the commentators alluded to, if you are looking for specific pH values of dishes rather than ingredients you'll probably want to use some pH strips to figure it out.

Also, if you are looking for more pH numbers on the internet, stay away from sites related to the "alkaline diet" as they seem to use some other system to determine alkalinity which doesn't appear to be related to pH. I found several sites that refer to lemons as "alkaline" which seems to be as far from the truth as I could imagine.

Comment: Well.. Thanks mate for your reference, I will read all of them. Yes.. My rules are simple, always stay away from marketing, it is evil and generally they just want our money. I just need to know the pH of raw ingredients, I do not need to measure the pH of our dishes. Thank You very much. Cheers!